# IE8 + Visual studio error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer

I finally let windows nag me into upgrading from IE6 to 8.

Now in visual studio 2008 when I try and edit an MFC dialog box, I get a "an error has occured on this page - continue running scripts? error"
The add variable screen has a warning "an add-on for this website failed to run"

Does Visual Studio 2008 work with IE8?
Is this some mysterious plot to stop people using MFC? (times are hard - I have to earn a living)
Any idea what magic setting I set to fix this?

edit - thanks to Mr Ghost, the solution is regedit.

```
Under “HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet 
Settings\Zones”, create a new key called 1000 (if it isn't already there)
-          Under 1000, create a DWORD entry with:
Name = 1207
Type = REG_DWORD
Data = 0x000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried Google first? The [First hit](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/03/28/some-vs2005-and-vs2008-wizards-pop-up-script-error.aspx) explains what it is and how to workaround it locally.

It has something to do with some security setting in the wizard's custom internet zone.

Comment: Thanks, I must have put different search terms. I just got posts about the beta and lots of speculation about how to fix it.