# IE8 and Visual Studio (2005/2008) - Current Status

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, internet-explorer-8

There have been a number of problems related to IE8 breaking Visual Studio 2005/2008.

Examples:

[IE8 + Visual studio error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926522/ie8-visual-studio-error)
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=426428
http://dpotter.net/Technical/2009/05/upgrading-to-ie8-breaks-debugging-with-visual-studio-2005/

Are there still specific issues with Visual Studio preventing you from installing IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on VS2005/2008 with IE8 for several months without problem now after changed the IE security zone and tabprocgrowth setting.

Comment: Here's a link for tabprocgrowth: http://weblogs.asp.net/abdullaabdelhaq/archive/2009/06/01/VS-Debug-Problem-with-IE8.aspx